# How to generate multiple short codes for multiple pages and multiple custom post type in WordPress Ajax search Lite plug in

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search, plugins

I'm using Ajax search lite plugin in one of my WordPress site.

I'm using this plugins for searching a custom post type (Doctor). I have placed the short code in home page.

But now I need more different short codes to use on another pages and also filtering on another custom post types.

So is there option to get multiple configured short codes so that I can dedicatedly use each one for specific custom post type.

For example I want to create one short code which will only search for doctors type post.
another short codes which will search only on medical type post.

I have seen only one short code there.